# Analysing a dataset that has mainly independent records but now has a few paired records

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, pseudorepliction

I am at the start of a project that collects data from subjects every 3 months. The data I currently have is nearly all independent (one record per subject, see screengrab below) but we've just hit the first 3 months milestone and have collected data from a few previously-sampled subjects, and so have added a few repeat measures to the data set.

You'll see that the entries highlighted in colour below (`Mickey, Meikle, Eddy, Ella`) show values for the response variable `OQS_NEG` at two time points, `MAY 23` and `AUG 23`. For *all other* records, there is currently only a single time point (since we're early in the data collection phase and they've not been sampled yet).

So my question:
How do I compare `OQS_NEG` mean/median with a single published reference value e.g. 0.40? I would normally use a one-sample t-test for this e.g. `t.test(data$OQS_NEG, mu=0.40)`, but since I have 'pockets' of within-subject pseudoreplication (coloured below) amongst the independent records, I feel I should be correcting for this, by using a mixed effect model. Problem is I'm not sure how I'd go about that...

I've also thought about using the mean/median of each of the paired data records so, for example, `Mickey` would only have 1 record not 2, but this seems wrong as I'd be losing variation within in each subject...

Any guidance towards the right direction would be immensely appreciated.

Many thanks, David

[image: dataset screegrab]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, data like this can be described as *semi-panel* data. For example, in recurring observational household survey research (not longitudinal) with large sample sizes and random sampling designs (like BLS studies), it has been noted that some households can see more than one occurrence in the study, an unintended outcome of the design. The literature on this is not large, here are some papers https://psyarxiv.com/akpmx/download?format=pdf  https://nashr.majles.ir/article_127.html?lang=en